# SQL Query "time" Reference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the below query in MS SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT t1.time, value, annotations
FROM PI.piarchive..picomp2 t1
WHERE tag = 'sinusoid'
      AND t1.time >= 't'
      AND annotated = 1
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the query, the below error is returned:
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

That tells me that it's trying to use the SQL in-built time reference, but preventing me from referring to the "time" attribute in the system table "PI.piarchive..picomp2".

Are you able to advise what changes in syntax I need to make to change the behaviour during query execution so it can query the "time" attribute in the "PI.piarchive..picomp2" table?

**EDITED**

The "time" attribute is of DateTime type, but since this is a historian I am querying via OLEDB, the reference of 't' (what I am trying to compare with) is a valid value as 't' refers to today.

Comment: What data type is your `time` column? I'm guessing it's trying to convert 't' to a time before comparing, but of course this is not a valid representation of a time. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi ElectricLlama! Thanks for the prompt reply! The "time" attribute is of DateTime type, but since this is a historian I am querying via OLEDB, the reference of 't' (what I am trying to compare with) is a valid value as 't' refers to today. I forgot to add the first sentence in the error message being "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1" and MS SQL Management Studio highlights the first line of the query, being 'SELECT t1.time,value,annotations' (meaning I suppose that's where the error is occurring).

Comment: @Mario, can you update your question by adding the additional information given in your comment? +10 for first question.

Comment: Hi J. Katzwinkel! Sorry, I just saw your recommendation! Someone already did this for me, so thank you for that! Will keep in mind next time :) Thanks a lot guys for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's said in the error message you are trying to compare value of data type `datetime` and character string. Of course, that's not aloud. How can you compare for example word 'ostrich' and current date? Which one is bigger or less?

You can compare `t1.time` with current date this way (SQL Server 2008+):

```
t1.time >= CAST(GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thank you for your help! I thought the OLEDB provider would be able to parse the 't' (that the PI Historian understands as a timestamp), but as it seems it doesn't. Thanks again! Cheers,